# Format SSIS Expressions for Easy Viewing

Tags: linq, ssis, expression

Is there a tool that is able to format or beautify `SSIS` `expressions` for ease of viewing?

Below is a sample expression. With all the brackets and `LINQ` `if-else` via `?` and `:` makes analysis painful.

```
(DT_WSTR,10)REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACENULL([category.tel_wo_code],"") == "001" && REPLACENULL([subcategory.tel_wo_code],"") == "001001" ? (REPLACENULL([NCDRCust.tel_com_spec_stock_partner],"") == "" ? [NCDRCust.tel_com_ship_to_party] : [NCDRCust.tel_com_spec_stock_partner]) : ((REPLACENULL([POSalesOrder.tel_com_spec_stock_partner],"") == "" ? (REPLACENULL([POSalesOrder.tel_com_ship_to_party],"") == "" ? (REPLACENULL([primaryso.tel_com_sales_doc_typename],"") == "ZE10" ? (REPLACENULL([secondaryso.tel_com_spec_stock_partner],"") == "" ? [secondaryso.tel_com_ship_to_party] : [secondaryso.tel_com_spec_stock_partner]) : (REPLACENULL([primaryso.tel_com_spec_stock_partner],"") == "" ? [primaryso.tel_com_ship_to_party] : [primaryso.tel_com_spec_stock_partner])) : [POSalesOrder.tel_com_ship_to_party]) : [POSalesOrder.tel_com_spec_stock_partner])),"\x0009"," "),"\x000D"," "),"\x000A"," ")
```

Comment: There isn't a tool specifically designed to format or beautify SSIS (SQL Server Integration Services) expressions, especially those that include complex nested structures as you provided.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No tool exists, which would be off topic for SO as it is.

The problem with beautifying an expression is that it only works in some places.

Using your expression, if I made it pretty like this (it's not pretty)

```
(DT_WSTR,10)
REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACE
(REPLACENULL([category.tel_wo_code],"") == "001" && REPLACENULL([subcategory.tel_wo_code],"") == "001001" 
? (REPLACENULL([NCDRCust.tel_com_spec_stock_partner],"") == "" 
? [NCDRCust.tel_com_ship_to_party] : [NCDRCust.tel_com_spec_stock_partner]) : ((REPLACENULL([POSalesOrder.tel_com_spec_stock_partner],"") == "" 
? (REPLACENULL([POSalesOrder.tel_com_ship_to_party],"") == "" 
? (REPLACENULL([primaryso.tel_com_sales_doc_typename],"") == "ZE10" 
? (REPLACENULL([secondaryso.tel_com_spec_stock_partner],"") == "" 
? [secondaryso.tel_com_ship_to_party] : [secondaryso.tel_com_spec_stock_partner]) : (REPLACENULL([primaryso.tel_com_spec_stock_partner],"") == "" 
? [primaryso.tel_com_ship_to_party] : [primaryso.tel_com_spec_stock_partner])) : [POSalesOrder.tel_com_ship_to_party]) : [POSalesOrder.tel_com_spec_stock_partner]))
,"\x0009"," ")
,"\x000D"," ")
,"\x000A"," ")
```

That would work in the Expression editor on a Variable. Those line breaks don't work in the Derived Column Task's expression section.

## What is the answer then?

Break it up into smaller, testable and debugable units.

If it's a data flow, add a bunch of Derived Columns that compute values that subsequent Derived Columns use

If it's Variables, add a bunch of Variables that compute values that subsequent Variables use.

That'd look like

`StockPartner` becomes

```
REPLACENULL([secondaryso.tel_com_spec_stock_partner],"") == ""
```

? [secondaryso.tel_com_ship_to_party] : [secondaryso.tel_com_spec_stock_partner]

`DocName` becomes

```
REPLACENULL([primaryso.tel_com_sales_doc_typename],"") == "ZE10 ? StockPartner : etc
```

A rule of thumb is "if you have to scroll to read the expression, it needs to be broken up into smaller units"